# Avoid type based function calls

Tags: swift, performance, if-statement, types

The code below is just example code to explain the program since the original is too complex and long. I create an instance of the `Game` object. It can be one of three `Cartypes`.
The `foo()` function in `MainClass` gets called over 100 times.
It seems counterintuitive to check the type of my object **every single time foo() gets called**, since I know the type of `obj` right in the beginning. I would like to avoid the if-statements for performance and simplicity reasons. What be a better way to implement this?

```
class Car{
   init(type: CarType, color: String){
      self.type = type
      self.color = color
   }
}

enum Cartypes{
   case sedan
   case pickup
   case coupe
}

class MainClass{
   // this is just an example, it could be any other cartype as well
   let obj = Car(type: .sedan, color: "red")
   
   func foo(){
      if obj.type == .sedan{
         doSedanStuff()
      } else if obj.type == .pickup{
         doPickupStuff()
      } else if obj.type == .coupe{
         doCoupeStuff()
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the `if` statement, it begs the question as to whether you can move this “stuff” into the types themselves.

For example, you might have a protocol:

```
protocol Car {
    func doCarStuff()
}

struct Sedan: Car {
    let color: String

    func doCarStuff() {
        print("go to the grocery store")
    }
}

struct Pickup: Car {
    func doCarStuff() {
        print("haul stuff to the dump")
    }
}

struct Coupe: Car {
    func doCarStuff() {
        print("go for spirited drive along the coast")
    }
}
```

And then you can use that protocol, eliminating the `if`/`switch` statements:

```
class MainClass {
    // this is just an example, it could be any other cartype as well
    let obj: Car = Sedan(color: "red")

    func foo() {
        obj.doCarStuff()
    }
}
```

---

By the way, I used `struct`, but works in `class` types, too. Also, you can make the `Car` conformance in the base definition or add it in an extension, whichever you prefer.

With `class`, you can also define base `Car` class and make the `Sedan`, `Coupe`, etc., types subclasses. The idea is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The whole organization here is very weird; it seems to me you've got three divisions into types where you only need one.

However, one answer to the actual question you asked is probably: this is what subclasses are for. Any time you find yourself checking a type in a class, that's a Bad Smell; you should have had three subtypes all along. To put it another way, subclasses *are* the implicit choice among types.

Another possibility is to inject the action of `foo` at the same time you inject what `obj` is. That might make more sense if the number of car types is open-ended. You still have to make the choice among types, but you only do it *once*, when the class is instantiated:

```
class Car {
    let type: CarType
    let color: String
    init(type: CarType, color: String){
       self.type = type
       self.color = color
    }
}
enum CarType {
   case sedan
   case pickup
   case coupe
}
class MainClass {
    let obj : Car
    var stuff : (() -> ())?
    init(car:Car) {
        self.obj = car
        if obj.type == .sedan{
            stuff = doSedanStuff
         } else if obj.type == .pickup{
            stuff = doPickupStuff
         } else if obj.type == .coupe{
            stuff = doCoupeStuff
         }
    }
   
    func foo(){
        stuff?()
    }
    func doSedanStuff() {}
    func doPickupStuff() {}
    func doCoupeStuff() {}
}
```